# hook_preprocess_html in my module

Tags: theming

I am having a content type with fields select list, js, css, and body. In the select box it list a number of templates to apply on the current node. I have these custom templates in the templates folder of the active theme, in the format

```
my-module-blank.tpl.php, my-module-custom1.tpl.php
```

And on select list I have blank and custom1 as options. In the hook_preprocess_node, using theme_hook_suggestions I have did the same,

```
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'my_module_' . $field_template_list;
```

But it is not taking the template, In addition I need to use hook_preprocess_html
to include the custom css and js added to fields of content type to the header portion. I didn't find any proper documentation on it.

Please show me a better documentation so that I could implement.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: @SumitMadan I wanted to know what is the purpose of html preprocess, would you mind providing a link to a good documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_page()` is called before `hook_preprocess_html()`. `hook_preprocess_html()` would probably be the last one that's run in a page build.

If you want your CSS and JavaScript when displaying a node, you can add the files it in the preprocess function for the node template.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $node =& $variables['node'];
    if ($node->type == 'something') {
      $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME');
      drupal_add_css($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-calls.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
    }
  }
}
```

You can add a custom template for any content type like:

```
node--[node-type].tpl.php
```

I would suggest you to use `hook_preprocess_page` at `template.php` for this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {  
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {
        if ($variables['node']->type == 'something') {
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to clear your cache after this :)